# Converting count data to binary "capture histories" while retaining NAs and covariates

Tags: r

I am attempting to take count data (of animals) from a depletion/removal study and convert it into binary capture histories for use in Program MARK.

The data has a structure of multiple counts for each row (i.e., c1, c2, ...) and multiple covariates (i.e., cov1, cov2, ...). Some of the counts contain missing values.

What I am trying to do is give each individual animal its own "capture history" consisting of 1's and 0's. Accordingly, the number of rows in the final data frame should be equal to the sum of the counts for all rows. The trouble I am running into is how to replicate rows while retaining missing values (i.e., NAs). If a row only contains zero's or NAs, it can be ignored. But if a row with some non-zero count has NAs in it, I want to retain those NAs in the final capture history.

I used dput to generate the following example matrix:

```
structure(c(3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
1997, 1997, 1998, 1999, 1999), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("c1", "c2", "c3", "cov")))
```

That code should produce the following:

```
# Original count data
######################
#      c1 c2 c3  cov #
# [1,]  3  2  1 1997 #
# [2,]  2 NA NA 1997 #
# [3,]  1  0 NA 1998 #
# [4,]  0  0  0 1999 #
# [5,]  0 NA NA 1999 #
######################
```

And this is what I want the MARK input to look like. Note that I do not need to keep the final rows from the original matrix because no individuals were observed:

```
# Desired binary data
####################
#   1  0  0 1997   #   # Where the first 3 rows represent the count in [1,1]
#   1  0  0 1997   #
#   1  0  0 1997   #
#   0  1  0 1997   #   # These next two represent the count in [1,2]
#   0  1  0 1997   #
#   0  0  1 1997   #   # This is [1,3]
#   1 NA NA 1997   #   # These are [2,1]
#   1 NA NA 1997   #
#   1  0 NA 1998   #   # And the last is [3,1]
####################
```

One other possible input format would be to place the count in a separate column. This and the above input contain identical information:

```
# Desired binary data
####################
#   1  0  0 1997 3 #   # Where the first row represents the count in [1,1]
#   0  1  0 1997 2 #   # These next represents the count in [1,2]
#   0  0  1 1997 1 #   # This is [1,3]
#   1 NA NA 1997 2 #   # This is [2,1]
#   1  0 NA 1998 1 #   # And the last is [3,1]
####################
```

Comment: Is the `NA` important or could it be `0` as well instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, the NA is important. I have no trouble manipulating the data into this format if I convert all the NA's to 0's.